# Keep python telegram bot running

Tags: python, server, telegram-bot

I made a telegram bot using python and the pyTelegramBotAPI api. The thing is, when I run my bot more than 5 minutes it throws an error "conection reset by peer". So I decided to do an infinite polling. with infinite polling stops working every 10 min for 1 min throwing:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

After that, It runs for 10 min more, but with this error:

```
    2018-08-01 21:16:27,187 (util.py:65 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "ApiException occurred, args=('A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 409 Conflict. Response
 body:\n[{"ok":false,"error_code":409,"description":"Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running"}]',)
```

And If I decide to send something in telegram, sometimes the bot make double response, It seems they are running two instances of the bot, but why?

There is a way to solve this? Maybe a shell scripting to terminate the process using scheduling every n minutes or something like that.

I tried also deploy with heroku with no sucess.

Every idea to keep that bot running is welcome. Here is my polling:

```
def principal():
    while True:
        try:
            bot.infinity_polling(True)
            bot.polling(none_stop=True)
        except:
            time.sleep(10)


principal()
```

Comment: How are you running your bot? What launches it?

Comment: Im running it localy `python bot.py`

Comment: Why is my question unclear? Please help by suggesting edit

Comment: Delete `bot.polling(none_stop=True)` - in my opinion you have to use only `bot.infinity_polling(True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems you're running into appear to be inherent to the pyTelegramBotAPI package -- they are not specific to your code. Other users have encountered the same issues:

- [409 Conflict on error inside handler](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/536); [Error 409 Conflict](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/543)
- [Max recursion depth crash](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/273); [RunTimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/531)

These issues appear to be inherent to the library, and do not appear to have been addressed by the library's author. Your best option may be to use another library. Failing that, some users have reported that disabling threading may help.

Comment: Im going to schedule task using crontab. But your solution was very helpful, I disabled threading and runs forever